# Replace paragraph text within a div based on class

Tags: jquery, replace

I'm trying to use jQuery to change paragraph text based upon the class of the div in which it resides.

I want each of the class names in the array to replace the p text within their respective divs. Right now I just get the last div's class name for the p text.

```
<div class="ph player">PHILIPPINES<p class="topic">Test topic</p></div>
<div class="sl player">SOLOMON ISLANDS<p class="topic">Test topic</p></div>
<div class="fi player">FIJI<p class="topic">Test topic</p></div>
<div class="sm player">SAMOA<p class="topic">Test topic</p></div>

<script>
var divArr = ["ph", "sl", "fi", "sm"];
$.each(divArr, function(index, value) {
   $(".topic").text(this);
});
</script>
```

Thanks for looking. Total beginner here.

Comment: Accept an answer. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 3):

I THINK what you want is:

```
$.each(divArr,function(i,val) {
  $('.'+val+' p.topic').text(val);
});
```

That will make the paragraph text of each div equal to the two letter class name

Comment: Correct, nice shorthand form. Upvoting.

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the appropriate `.topic` not all `.topic`s:

```
var divArr = ["ph", "sl", "fi", "sm"];
$.each(divArr, function(index, value) {
   $('.' + value).find(".topic").text(this);
});
```

Comment: Mahalo! I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are only selecting the div you want to change:

```
var divArr = ["ph", "sl", "fi", "sm"];
$.each(divArr, function(index, value) {
   $("div." + value + " .topic").text(value);
});
```

Comment: My bad, downvote is gone :) @Andrew, now upvoted. I read your code wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(divArr, function (i,e) { 
    $("."+this).find("p.topic").text(this);
});
```

The key is to correctly use the selectors.

"`this`" takes the values "ph", "sl"...

So `"."+this` will identify classes in JQuery/CSS syntax (.ph, .sl ...)

`$("."+this)` therefore selects the correct `div`, in which we will fine `p` tags with class `.topic` and substitute the text (again, `this`).